# How To save Geo-Tiff image in PostgresSQL?

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql

```
I have a Geotiff image, which I want to load into a PostgreSQL database.
```

Currently I am using the command line code for saving this image to my database :

```
raster2pgsql -I -C -e -Y -F -s 26986 -t 128x128  -l 2,4 
    C:\Users\Digital-Globe-Quickbird\pyramids_geotiff.tif public.boston 
| psql -U postgres -d test -h 8.35.193.103 -p 5432
```

And after Run this command it creates one table for that image and stores the data in it.
Now I want to fetch the data from the table and plot it on Google map.
I am executing this query on pgAdmin for fetching the data :

```
select rid,rast::geometry from boston limit 10;
```

And I get the output like this :

[image: ![enter image description here]

Now I don’t know  how to plot this data on Google map. please let me know how can do this.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how to ask a question. There are at least 3 questions here, 2 of which are very broad.

Comment: You've got ArcGIS Desktop as the first tag, but no mention of it in the question. Please **edit** the Question to contain one question.

Comment: The script you ran above, loads the tiff into Postgres/Postgis. What do you mean by is there any way to do it with Postgis? Do what/

Comment: How close is your workstation to server?  Could be a network issue.  Also how big is this tif file? You can use QGIS Db Manager tool for viewing PostGIS raster.

Comment: Thanks @John Barca , Right now I am doing this using CMD (Command Line ) ,I want to do  without  CMD ,So is there  any  tool  to import tiff image into postages database.

Comment: Is the intention to show the data as a map?  If so I think you'll have to do some sort of image conversion, either directly or indirectly by providing the data through a WMS.